# Proper syntax for adding Rundeck Ansible "Extra Vars"

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x, rundeck

Im using Rundeck 3.0.7 with Ansible 2.7 and cant figure out the correct syntax to pass variables to my Ansible playbook. If I run it from the command line it works fine.

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i hosts -e "FirstName=John LastName=Doe OfficePhone=365"
```

However when I add those vars to the "Extra Variables" section of the Rundeck Job I add the following and it doesnt work.

```
-e "FirstName=John LastName=Doe OfficePhone=365"
```

Does anyone know the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your workflow define your playbook extra arguments using options like:

```
-e "test1=${option.test1} test2=${option.test2}"
```

That way you get the values of options to those variable names in the arguments to ansible-playbook.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "Extra Variables" section with the yaml syntax e.g.

```
FirstName: John
LastName: Doe
OfficePhone: 365
```

This can also be done with variables passed from Rundeck to Ansible:

**Extra Variables:**

```
FirstName: ${option.firstname}
LastName: ${option.lastname}
OfficePhone: ${option.phone}
```

Then of course you need the Rundeck options defined.

[Source](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin/issues/10#issuecomment-253994913)