# Rundeck pass variable between two ansible tasks

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I am trying to pass variable between two playbooks with Rundeck.
First playbook output filtered with Global filter, data is captured into data.variable.

That seems good to me, I can use it in exec task, e.g. `echo ${data.variable}`

I would like to use the content of this variable in second ansible playbook, but if I add `${data.variable}` as `extra_var` the result is empty in playbook.

Ofc. if I define some extra_vars from gui ( `${option.extravar}` - works well).

This is not an inline playbook.

Comment: Could you try exporting the data variable and using the export variable on the second playbook? similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72364741/10426011

Comment: Also, did you try in this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064117/10426011